# send impression when a card is shown on Android RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app I show cards in a RecyclerView in a fragment contained in a ViewPager. Some of these cards contain adverts. When a card with an advert is shown I need to report the "impression".

I didn't find a good way to implement it. Is there a way to know when a card is shown? Consider that the binding of the holder is sometimes done in advance since every time I load a page I load the previous and next page too.  So the cards in the next page are already bound to the holder even if they are not shown yet.

**I need a way to know when the card is actually shown.**

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: do you find any solution ... I also what it.

Comment: This is too old so I don't remember the details but I would have posted the solution if I had found it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only way is by checking every time the cards that are actually shown when the fragment starts

Comment: I would need to manually check every time the user scrolls the list of the cards

Comment: And I can't check when the fragment is started because the next page fragment is started as well even if it is not shown